# autochdir working with :sp but not :e?

Tags: command-line, working-directory

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 (x86_64) and vim 7.4. In [my config file](https://gist.github.com/ShabbyX/3691170), I have:

```
set autochdir
```

And this was working for as long as I remember. Just after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, I see the following behavior (assume `pwd` is `/path`):

- The following commands (`z` is a file):

  ```
  $ vim X/Y/z
  :e .
  ```

  result in vim showing the contents of `/path`.
- The following commands:

  ```
  $ vim X/Y/z
  :sp .
  ```

  result in vim showing the contents of `/path/X/Y`.
- The following commands:

  ```
  $ vim X/Y/z
  :sp .
  :q
  :e .
  ```

  also result in vim showing the contents of `/path/X/Y`.

The expected behavior for me was for all three cases to open `/path/X/Y`. But it seems like `:sp` is changing the current directory, but `:e` is not. Before my upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04, I am sure all three cases did the same thing (open `/path/X/Y`).

Can anybody else reproduce this? Is this intended behavior and documented?

---

Additionally, if I do:

```
$ vim X/Y/z
:sp ./<TAB>          --or--
:e ./<TAB>           --or--
:w ./<TAB>
```

then vim iterates through the items in the `X` directory, not `X/Y`. Although if I do `:sp ./X/w` where `X` and `w` were selected using `<TAB>` (i.e. vim finds the items based on the current directory), the file is not actually opened (an empty new file is opened, as if the file doesn't exist). This suggests that `autochdir` has worked where opening the file is concerned, but hasn't worked where listing directory items is concerned.

Comment: I had same problem i just mapped 
nnoremap <Leader>e :e <C-R>=expand('%:p:h') . '/'<CR>
To get around it

Comment: `:e filename` respects `autochdir` but `:e directory` starts the netrw plugin which doesn't respect `autochdir` by default. See `:help netrw` for a solution.

Comment: @romainl, interesting. Although `:help netrw` doesn't really offer a solution.

Comment: @romainl, by the way, how is it that before Ubuntu 16.04 I never had this problem, even though I was still using vim 7.4?

Comment: @romainl please see my edit. The issue seems to be deeper than that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be an issue that was introduced in a patch that was picked up by Ubuntu 16.04 and fixed in another patch.  Here's a link to the [bug report](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/704).  It was fixed in [patch 1716](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/baec5c1768098f9dd867b465aaabfdfb294f10c2) but, unfortunately, 16.04 shipped with patches only up to 1689.

Hopefully there'll be an update soon.  Otherwise it's compile the latest version from source, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. It's a hell of an annoying issue, so I certainly hope Ubuntu picks up the fix.

Comment: @Shahbaz There's [pi-rho's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+archive/ubuntu/dev) if you don't want to wait.

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my .vimrc and now it works as desired:

```
" Automatically set current directory to browsing directory.                                                      
let g:netrw_keepdir=0
```

For more information: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#g:netrw_keepdir